# Django urlresolvers.reverse not working for "|" within non-capturing group

Tags: django

I have in my test:

```
url = reverse('record-list')
```

for my service/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^records/?$', RecordList.as_view(), name='record-list'),
...
```

which is also loaded into my project urls.py with:

```
for app in apps['apps']:
    try:
        _module = import_module('%s.urls' % app)
    except:
        if settings.DEBUG:
            raise
        else:
            pass
    else:
        urlpatterns += [url(r'^api/%s(?:/|/?$)' % app, include('%s.urls' % app))]
```

and getting the error

```
django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'record-list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['api/service(?:/|/?$)records/?$']
```

Why does the capturing group in the middle of the url cause `reverse` to fail?

Comment: reverse('record-list') - no parameter send, (?:/|/?$) one parameter need.

Comment: It's a non capturing group, so no parameters are needed

Comment: without (?:/|/?$) app work?

Comment: Yes, but that would defeat the purpose of this question.

Comment: url(r'^pub/(?P<slug>[0-9A-Z]+)/$, ? = parameter.  ^api/%s(?:/|/?$) ? == ^api/%s(?<data>:/|/?$) first value?

Comment: `?:` denotes a non-capturing group in regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because the regex parser for `reverse` simply cannot handle `|` symbols within the regex. It hasn't been implemented yet.

See https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.9.x/django/utils/regex_helper.py#L98

Comment: That comment is a bit misleading. There's a good reason this hasn't been done: given a choice of valid groups, which one should be chosen in a reverse call?